# Images rotated in Chrome

Tags: html, css, exif

I am designing a website and whenever I use images either in CSS or HTML they always appear flipped, after some googling I found that this has something to do with EXIF data and various other meta tags but my question is why this happens and if it is avoidable (different file format etc)? Further, I also found that if I reload the image with javascript after the image already loaded, it will be the correct orientation for some reason.

Comment: Could you please add a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome will in certain cases attempt to orient the image according to the [Orientation tag](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html) in the EXIF metadata. There is additional info in this issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=56845

To avoid this, the best solution would be to strip the Orientation tag from the image's EXIF metadata. You might want to simply remove all the EXIF data in any case since it may leak personal information.

You can remove all EXIF metadata with [`exiftool`](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/):

```
exiftool -all= file.jpg
```

Or just remove the Orientation property:

```
exiftool -Orientation= file.jpg
```

There are many online tools that will also let you manipulate the EXIF data.